# how to loop through File stream

Tags: c, linux, loops, unix

I would like to know if there is a way I can loop through a FILE *ptr so that I can get its size.For example:

```
char *buffer = malloc(512);
FILE *command = popen("pwd","r");
pclose(command);
```

I would like to loop through *command output until the end and create a counter size++
that way I can calculate its size.
But I don't know how to do the loop here.
If anyone could please tell me if this is possible and how.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only read data from the pipe once.  If you want to calculate the amount of data, you will need to store it all and count.  Something like:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void * xrealloc(void *buf, size_t num, size_t siz, void *end);
struct string{ char *start, *end; size_t cap; };

static void
push(int c, struct string *b)
{
        if( b->start == NULL || b->end >= b->start + b->cap ) {
                b->start = xrealloc(b->start, b->cap += 128,
                        sizeof *b->start, &b->end);
        }
        *b->end++ = c;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int c;
        int text = 1;
        char *cmd = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "pwd";
        struct string content = {0};
        FILE *command = popen(cmd,"r");
        if( command == NULL ) {
                perror("pwd");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        while( (c = getc(command)) != EOF ){
                push(c, &content);
                if( ! isprint(c) && ! isspace(c)) {
                        text = 0;
                }
        }
        printf("%zu bytes\n", content.end - content.start);
        if( text ) {
                push('\0', &content);
                printf("%s", content.start);
        }
        return 0;
}
static void *
xrealloc(void *buf, size_t num, size_t siz, void *endvp)
{
        void **endp = endvp;
        ptrdiff_t offset = endp && *endp ? *endp - buf : 0;
        buf = realloc(buf, num * siz);
        if( buf == NULL ){
                perror("realloc");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if( endp != NULL ){
                *endp = buf + offset;
        }
        return buf;
}
```

Comment: Just a two simple doubts
1- Why is *b->end++ = c works, but not the other way around I mean c = *b->end++. 
I know the results are different but it is a assignment in both ways.
2- And why I can't declare struct string *content = {0} instead of content without pointer; when I use the pointer and modify the code to use content->something it stops working.

It may sound odd but I'm still learning the C language there are some things I don't really understand.
And by the way thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: `*b->end++ = c` works because it puts the value of c into the correct  location.  `c = *b->end++` cannot work because `*b->end` is uninitialized so attempting to read its value is undefined behavior and c is a local variable so assigning it just before returning from the function is pointless.

Comment: You cannot declare `struct string *content = {0}` because the value on the right hand side of the initializer is of the wrong type.  You could do `struct string a; struct string *content = &a`.